# Is there an example that a specific matrix has Jordan block $J_{2}(i)$?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, jordan-normal-form, skew-symmetric-matrices

Consider a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
 A & C\\
 -C^{T} & B
 \end{bmatrix}$ where A and B are symmetric matrices.

Can matrices of this type have a Jordan normal form representation with Jordan blocks of the form $J_{2}(i) = \begin{bmatrix}
 i & 1\\
 0 & i
 \end{bmatrix}$? I'm trying to find such an example but I can't find it until now. Please help me..

Thanks